# Why is _ undefined when using Miso?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm trying to use Miso (http://misoproject.com/dataset/), and on of the dependencies is underscore.js.  I'm using require.js, and keep getting an error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined."  Here is my main.js file:

```
require(["jquery", "underscore", "miso"], function($, _, miso) {

  $(function() {
    var ds = new Miso.Dataset({
      url : "/data/ma_region.csv",
      delimiter : " ",
    });
  });

});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using node.js?

Comment: @Kyle, yes I'm using node

Comment: I think you don't have your underscore.js in the same path as  your javascript file

Comment: Underscore is not AMD compatible and requires a `shim` config option to be applied. It sounds as though `miso` will need it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miso is expecting the `_` underscore in the global scope.

In Miso's code:

```
(function(global, _) {

    /* has bunch of stuff using underscore */

}(this, _));
```

Which means that in this last part `(this, _)`, it doesn't have reference to `_` underscore library because it's defined within RequireJS which means it exists in the anonymous function scope.

So you need to load `_` underscore when and wrap Miso in a module, eg:

```
define(['underscore'], function(_) {

 /** Miso's code here because Miso is expecting the _ **/

});
```

You'll need to include this for the other dependencies listed on Miso's website http://misoproject.com/dataset/tutorials/quickstart:

> Dependencies
>
> If you chose to include the production version without
>   built in dependencies, you may need to include them yourself. Dataset
>   requires the following libraries:
>
> - LoDash 0.9.0
> - Underscore.math.js (unknown version)
> - Underscore.deferred.js 0.2.0
> - moment.js 1.7.2 (for 'time' data type)
>
> If you are using IE, you will want to include json2.js:
>
> - json2.js 2011-10-19

Alternatively, I recommend using the versions of Miso that already prepackage the dependencies so you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your underscore library is named underscore.js and it is in the same same directory as your javascript code. This is the baseURL for require.js.

If this isn't the case, you should configure paths. Refer http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths